# Did Shaun Temple know anything about Donna's travels with the Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

The Tenth Doctor's last long-term Companion, Donna Noble, was forced to stop travelling with him after (*Journey's End* [2008] spoilers)

> she had a two-way biological meta-crisis with him, absorbing his knowledge, and he had to wipe her memory of him before the Time Lord knowledge inside her head killed her.

It's clear from *The End of Time* that her mother and grandfather still knew about her earlier adventures with the Doctor, and were doing their best to protect her from ever having those memories come back to her and kill her. Also in *The End of Time*, we saw her marriage to Shaun Temple, a man who presumably came into her life after her travels with the Doctor.

In the newly released episode "The Star Beast" (2023), it remains clear that Donna's mother remembers the Doctor and is still doing her best (in a comedically clumsy way) to protect Donna from remembering him. **What about Shaun Temple?** Did his mother-in-law or grandfather-in-law ever tell him that he must protect Donna from any alien goings-on (which are shockingly frequent in the Whoniverse's London)? Or is he as blissfully unaware as the memory-wiped Donna of any of his family's involvement with extraterrestrial stuff?

Comment: Your Princess is in another castle; https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/We_Are_Family_(short_story)